# Как прибить процесс на основе аргументов командной строки?

Tags: windows, cmd, процесс

Хочу из командной строки завершить все процессы с именем `browser.exe` и параметром `--type=renderer` (одновременно).

Пока додумался только до того, чтобы посмотреть процессы с тем же именем и другими аргументами в диспетчере задач и исключить их:

```
taskkill /F /FI "PID ne 11908" /FI "PID ne 10164" /IM browser.exe
```

Но каждый раз смотреть id исключений не хочется. Как сделать нормально?

PS: Если есть ответ под linux, то тоже пригодится. Но windows приоритетнее, поскольку в его диспетчере задач нельзя выделить сразу пачку процессов для прибивания.

Comment: `kill $(ps -ef | grep browser.exe |  grep -- --type=renderer | awk '{ print $2 }')`

Comment: @avp, а через pkill не выйдет?

Comment: Наверное выйдет, но там man читать надо (я ее не помню...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WMIC](http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/wmic.html) - довольно запутанная, но мощная вещь, с помощью которой можно творить великое колдунство:

```
wmic path win32_process where "CommandLine like '%--type=renderer%' and Caption like '%browser.exe%'" call terminate
```

Comment: Работает, хотя и несколько странно: вместо http://i.stack.imgur.com/mZrml.png получается http://i.stack.imgur.com/4LTS7.png. Почему так?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685691/178988 - помоги?