# Chrome, wmic и PuntoSwitcher

Tags: windows, google-chrome, администрирование, процесс

После запуска ярлыка с командой

```
C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe path win32_process where "CommandLine like '%--type=renderer%' and Caption like '%chrome.exe%'" call terminate
```

или команды

```
taskkill /F /FI "PID ne 10936" /FI "PID ne 7868" /FI "PID ne 10416" /IM chrome.exe
```

возникает проблема, что PuntoSwitcher некорректно работает с Хромом. А именно, перестаёт работать переключение клавишей break с русского на английский (с английского на русский либо работает, либо нет), а так же PuntoSwitcher перестаёт определять, какая раскладка сейчас активна в Хроме. Shift+Break работает, автопереключение отключено.

Интересно, что если прибивать процессы хрома (с тем же параметром `--renderer`) руками из диспетчера задач, то проблемы нет, всё работает как должно.

Интересует любой способ решения проблемы:

- Как прибивать поцессы вкладок Хрома (имя процесса `chrome.exe` и команда запуска содержит `--type=renderer`), чтобы это ничего лишнего не портило? Особенно с учётом того, что часть процессов в хромовском диспетчере задач [не отображается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1116846/178988).
- Что можно сделать, чтобы пунтосвитчер продолжал корректно работать с хромом?

Информация:

- Windows 7 x64, Windows 10 x64
- Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (Официальная сборка) и более новые, (64 бит)
- PuntoSwitcher 4.2.6 от 03.06.2016 сборка 1275 и новее (4.3.6 от 17.02.2017
  сборка 1853)
- Перезапуск PuntoSwitcher'а не помогает

Всё ещё актуально:

- Windows 10 x64
- Google Chrome 81.0.4044.122 (Официальная сборка) (64 бит) (cohort: Stable)
- Версия 4.4.3 от 04.07.2018 сборка 407
- Сейчас получилось так: break не работает ни в какую сторону, значок пунтосвитчера меняется на текстовый `Ru` (возможно это был язык в момент прибивания вкладок, но я не уверен) и не обновляется при переключении языка, но только когда активно окно хрома. В других программах работает корректно и отображается флагом, как выставлено в настройках.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594645/178988

Comment: Попробуйте написать в поддержку яндекса о баге.

Comment: @ReklatsMasters, во-первых, почему яндекса, а не Хрома? Во-вторых, они ж ответят, что нечего по чужим процессам лазить, не?

Comment: @Qwerty очевидно потому, что проблема в пунтосвичере, именно он перестаёт работать. Возможно они хук или указатели как то не правильно освобождают. И вообще это сам пунтосвичер лазит по всем процессам и свои dll внедряет., а автор просто пытается закрыть процессы.

Comment: И у путно, и Гугла уже не первый год висят эти вопросы. и те и другие делают вид, что проблемы нет