# Лишние процессы хрома

Tags: google-chrome, процесс

Имеется куча лишних процессов хрома, которые не отображаются в его диспетчере задач. Т. е. даже если через хромовский диспетчер задач прибить все вкладки, остаётся более 50 запущенных процессов.

Что это за процессы? Принадлежат ли они какому-то сайту или расширению? Как узнать, какому именно? Как от них избавиться? Почему они в хромовском диспетчере не отображаются?

[image: скриншот]

> **Google Chrome** 81.0.4044.122 (Официальная сборка) (64 бит) (cohort: Stable)
>   **Версия**  44f4233f08910d83b146130c1938256a2e05b136-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#963}
>   **ОС**  Windows 10 OS Version 1909 (Build 18363.778)
>   **JavaScript**  V8 8.1.307.31
>   **Flash**   32.0.0.363 C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer64_32_0_0_363.dll
>   **User Agent**  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36
>   **Командная строка**    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --enable-audio-service-sandbox -- https://habr.com/ru/post/497544/

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/61468698/4928642)

Comment: Наверно хрому стало скучно и он решил помайнить биткоины.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это расширения. Убивается из контекстного меню "Завершить дерево процессов". Могут завершиться многие, но не все. При необходимости повторить.

Comment: Расширения в диспетчере хрома тоже показываются. Их у меня около 4 штук. Это точно не 50 расширений болтаются. Для дерева процессов непонятно, как выбрать корневой.